# Help Identifying Fruit

Tags: identification, fruits

[image: Fruit image]

I was hoping someone may be able to identify this fruit that was picked unripe. I was thinking maybe a Tamarillo but not sure. Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks so much for the response.  Here's a photo of the tree.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be a quince. They have fuzz all over the skin and the skin turns yellow when ripe.
If you know where you picked it maybe compare the leaves of the tree as well?